# How to create a hidden partition on a hard drive?

Tags: partition

I have created 3 partitions on a hard drive.

I've tried renaming the partition with a dot in front, however it seems that the OS doesn't allow that.

How to make one of the 3 partitions hidden to the user?

Comment: Hidden in what way? Not mounted by default? Mounted but not displayed as a volume? Something else?

Comment: Mounted but not displayed on the desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My previous answer is preserved below.

You can use the `chflags` command to apply the `hidden` attribute:

```
chflags hidden /Volumes/Hide_this_disk
```

And to unhide:

```
chflags nohidden /Volumes/Hide_this_disk
```

These commands should take effect immediately.

---

You need to have the Apple Developer **Command Line Tools** installed. You can either get them from inside of Xcode (in **Preferences** under **Downloads**) or you can download them from [Apple's Developer website](http://developer.apple.com/) (free registration required).

After it's installed you'll have the `SetFile` command:

```
SetFile -a V /Volumes/Hide_this_disk
```

This needs to be executed as `root`, and it won't vanish right away. But after remounting it, it won't be displayed in the Finder any more. You'll need to use **Disk Utility** (or `diskutil`) to mount and unmount the disk afterward since it won't be visible to unmount and it will still be available under `/Volumes` normally.

If it's an internal disk then I *believe* that it will auto-mount at boot, but I don't know for certain.

To make it visible again just run the same thing, but with a small `v`:

```
SetFile -a v /Volumes/Hide_this_disk
```

Again, you'll need to remount it.

Comment: Thanks, though I just realized that an easier way to do this is to use chflags instead.  I think it does the same thing, but it doesn't require the command line tools installed.

Comment: Ah, that's right. I couldn't remember the name of the other command. Updating my answer to include that.

Comment: As fyi, `/usr/bin/SetFile` was deprecated with Xcode 6 along as were other tools supporting Carbon development; although `SetFile` still appears to install as part of Xcode 12 command line tools.